# Limit and function inequality on Topology.

Tags: general-topology, limits, functions

Hi i really hope you can help me, i have been thinking this problem for a long time and i just did it but just with epsilom-delta definition and i don't know how to generalized it, any help will be really appreciated, thank you so much.

The problem says, let $(X, \tau)$ a topological space and $(\mathbb{R}, \tau')$ the real line, where $M\subset X$, $x_0\in M'$ and given a functions $f, g:M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) < \lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)$, prove that there is an open set $V \in \tau$, $x_0 \in V$ such that for all $x \in V\cap (M - \{x_0\})$ we can verify that $f(x)< g(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L=\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ and $M=\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$. Let $\epsilon =\frac {M-L} 2$. There exists set $V_1,V_2$ in $\tau$ containing $x_0$ such that $|f(x)-L| <\epsilon$ if $x \in V_1, x\neq x_0$ and $|g(x)-M| <\epsilon$ if $x \in V_2, x\neq x_0$. Let $V=V_1\cap V_2$.  If $x \in V$ and $x \leq x_0$ then $f(x)<L+\epsilon =M-\epsilon < g(x)$.

Comment: thanks so much, i didn't have any idea about how to do it